# Programmatically get list of sites in Liferay

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-7

I want to get the list of sites in Liferay, the same that appears at http://localhost:8080/group/control_panel/manage/-/sites/sites :

[image: Liferay sites]

In SQL I would run `select * from Group_ WHERE site=1`.

How to get the same thing in Java?

[GroupServiceUtil](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/7.0-ga3/javadocs/portal-kernel/com/liferay/portal/kernel/service/GroupServiceUtil.html) does not seem to have such a method.

Note: My Java code is in a module running within Liferay, but not a portlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `public List<Group> getGroups(long companyId, long parentGroupId, boolean site)` of GroupLocalServiceUtil (https://docs.liferay.com/dxp/digital-enterprise/7.0-sp1/javadocs/portal-kernel/com/liferay/portal/kernel/service/GroupLocalServiceUtil.html#getGroups-long-long-boolean-). It should be callable when you are not inside a OSGi based portlet. If you inside of a OSGi Component, you could inject GroupLocalService.
If you do not care about parentGroup, you could use GroupConstants.ANY_PARENT_GROUP_ID as parentGroupId instead.

Comment: I just saw that GroupServiceUtil also offers this [getGroups](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/7.0-ga3/javadocs/portal-kernel/com/liferay/portal/kernel/service/GroupServiceUtil.html#getGroups-long-long-boolean-) operation. You could also call it with GroupConstants.ANY_PARENT_GROUP_ID and site=true